# UI text Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to move a UI text relative to Camera movement in Unity?
Want to move a UItext relative to camera movement in unity.Tried code exanples such as
    using UnityEngine;
      using System.Collections;

```
  public class SortingLayerExposer : MonoBehaviour
  {

          public string SortingLayerName = "Default";
          public int SortingOrder = 0;

          void Awake ()
          {
                  gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().sortingLayerName = SortingLayerName;
                  gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().sortingOrder = SortingOrder;
          }
  }
```

But not able to move my text realtive to camera.

Comment: Is it a worldspace canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to add the texts to the camera-gameobject as children. They will automatically follow the camera. If you need to adjust the position further by script, you can modify the texts localpositions - as this will keep it relative.

Answer (score 0):

Using the *canvas* builtin gameobject type, everything attatched under the canvas will follow the camera and stay in position relative to screensize. you can also lock ui elements in specific locations on the screen using anchor points

[image: creating a canvas]

[image: Anchor points]